# QStandardItemModel::appendRow. Как правильно добавить и получить обратно строку

Tags: qt, mvc

Не добавляются строки (или не находятся добавленные?) в `QStandardItemModel`.

Вот, собственно, код:

```
    QStandardItem * pProduct = new QStandardItem("3");
    pProduct->setData("product", strProductName);
    this->appendRow(pProduct);

    QList<QStandardItem *> entries = this->findItems("product");
    qDebug() << entries.count();
```

И соответственно вывод всегда `0`.
Что я делаю не так? 
Как правильно добавить и получить обратно строку?

**UPD:** 
удалось локализовать проблему:

```
    QStandardItem * pChildEntry = new QStandardItem(QString("name"));
    pChildEntry->setData(QString("product"), strProductName);
    model.appendRow(pChildEntry);
    qDebug() << model.rowCount();

    QList<QStandardItem *> entries = model.findItems(QString("product"));
    entries.count();
```

Количество строк выводит нормально, следовательно не работает поиск, а не добавление строк

Comment: `void QStandardItem::setData(const QVariant & value, int role = Qt::UserRole + 1)`. Что в Вашем коде означает второй параметр?

Comment: Это объявленное в хэдере перечисление:  enum PRODUCT_MODEL_ROLES {
  strProductName = Qt::UserRole,
  strName, ... и т.д
  strAbout,

Comment: Установка стандартной роли Qt::DisplayRole ситуацию не спасла. Может вообще строка добавляется, но не находится? можно как то просмотреть модель после добавления (без вывода в интерфейс пользователя)?

Comment: Можно посмотреть. Вывести на консоль или взглянуть в отладчике.

Comment: Модель??? У меня в отладчике только адреса, а в консоль что выводить - если результата  finditems нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строки можно добавлять, например, так:

```
QStandardItemModel model(10, 10);
QList<QStandardItem*> row;
for (int i = 0; i < model.colCount(); i++)
{
    QStandardItem* item = new QStandardItem(QString("column %1").arg(i));
    row.append(item);
}
model.append(row);
```

Если в модели только один столбец, то можно чуть проще:

```
QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(0, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    model->appendRow(new QStandardItem(QString("Row %1").arg(i)));
```

Метод `QStandardItemModel::findItems` производит поиск, сравнивая только данные, имеющие роль `Qt::DisplayRole`. Следующий код

```
QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel();

QStandardItem* item0 = new QStandardItem("Item0");
model->appendRow(item0);
qDebug() << "Item0:" << model->findItems("Item0").count();

QStandardItem* item1 = new QStandardItem();
item1->setData("Item1", Qt::DisplayRole);
model->appendRow(item1);
qDebug() << "Item1:" << model->findItems("Item1").count();

QStandardItem* item2 = new QStandardItem();
item1->setData("Item2", Qt::UserRole);
model->appendRow(item2);
qDebug() << "Item2:" << model->findItems("Item2").count();
```

выводит в консоль

```
Item0: 1
Item1: 1
Item2: 0
```

Таким образом, если Вы установили данные вызовом метода `QStandardItem::setData` со вторым параметром, отличным от `Qt::DisplayRole`, `QStandardItemModel::findItems` эти данные не найдёт.

Comment: Как ни странно у меня есть работающий класс-модель, наследованный от QStandardItem, то есть синтаксис этот мне знаком и в одном месте работает. Но почему-то попытка создать похожий - провалилась. Возможно дело и правда в неправильных ролях (в работающем классе они у меня стандартные)

Comment: Спсибо за ответ, помогло! Как то я просмотрела что поиск идет только по одной роли :)